# GraphQL: react-apollo client overwrites array elements

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a GraphQL query that returns an array of items. I can run the query in *GraphiQL* and get the result I expected.

I have a react application that uses `react-apollo` and the `@graphql` decorator to resolve the very same query to component props. When running the query via `react-apollo`, every item in the returned array is the same - each item has been 'overwritten' by the last item.

I can see in the dev-tools network tab that the correct array items were sent over the network, so the issue seems to relate to react-apollo. What could be causing react-apollo to overwrite array elements?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: It's not really practical to post code that involves a GraphQL schema, a server, a react application and a react-redux implementation. In this case though I'm not sure it's necessary - I'm asking if there are any common reasons for misconfigurations that might cause this.

Comment: Since you said GraphiQL gives you the expected result, I think your server code does not have issues. The problem could be on the client side. I recollect any common reasons. i.e reducers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that my `qgl` fragment for the query did not include the `id` property for the items in the Array.

If you have a similar issue, ensure your schema includes an `id` or `_id` property on each item; that each `id` value is unique, and that you are requesting the `id` property in your query. Alternatively you can supply a `dataIdFromObject` function in your client to dynamically generate IDs for values.

You can read more in the Apollo docs for [Normalization with dataIdFromObject](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject)

Comment: It appears you also get this strange behaviour if `id` is present but is an object. My query was returning a JSON structure like `[{ "id": { "value": 1 } }, { "id": { "value": 2 } }]`, and apparently that doesn't work. I've flattened my data out and now it works.